# Read tar file on remote SSH server without using FTP in Python

Tags: python, ssh, ftp, tar

I am creating some tar file on a remote server and I want to be able to get it to my machine. Due to security reasons I can't use FTP on that server.

So how I see it, I have two options:

1. get the file (as file) in some other way and then use tarfile library - if so, I need help with getting the file without FTP.
2. get the content of the file and then extract it.

If there is another way, I would like to hear it.

```
import spur

#creating the connection
shell = spur.SshShell(
    hostname=unix_host,
    username=unix_user,
    password=unix_password,
    missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept
    )

# running ssh command that is creating a tar file on the remote server
with shell:
    command = "tar -czvf test.gz test"
    shell.run(
        ["sh", "-c", command],
        cwd=unix_path
        )

    # getting the content of the tar file to gz_file_content
    command = "cat test.gz"
    gz_file_content = shell.run(
        ["sh", "-c", command],
        cwd=unix_path
        )
```

More info:
My project is running on a virtualenv. I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: if you have ssh, then maybe you have scp or sftp.

Comment: Don't use `missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept`! You are losing protection against [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SSH access, you have SFTP access for 99%.

So you can use the SFTP to download the file. See [Download files over SSH using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29508743/850848).

---

Or once you are using spur, see its [`SshShell.open` method](https://pypi.org/project/spur/#open-path-mode-r):

> For instance, to copy a binary file over SSH, assuming you already have an instance of `SshShell`:
>
> ```
> with ssh_shell.open("/path/to/remote", "rb") as remote_file:
>     with open("/path/to/local", "wb") as local_file:
>         shutil.copyfileobj(remote_file, local_file)
> ```

*The `SshShell.open` method uses SFTP under the hood (via Paramiko library).*