# SSH into server using python script

Tags: python, ssh

I am an astronomy student working with large data set. I have 80 TB of .fits file on a supercomputer that I am trying to process using python script. I could process the data stored on the supercomputer by submitting a job(which stays in queue 
 for ages) or I could process the data in my local desktop(without downloading all the data). However, I cannot download all(80TB) data to my local desktop due to storage issue. I was wondering if there is a way to run the processing python script on my local desktop but it reads data from the supercomputer using secure shell.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file from server with ssh using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596963/read-a-file-from-server-with-ssh-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python)  and [Download files over SSH using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508743/download-files-over-ssh-using-python) [How to list all the folders and files in the directory after connecting through sftp in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295551/how-to-list-all-the-folders-and-files-in-the-directory-after-connecting-through)

You could put it in a loop and get a file > Parse it > get next file and so on.